# Using namespace in DataTemplate DataType

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, namespaces, datatemplate

I am trying to show a list of videos from YouTube using a ListBox and the ItemsSource property.

What I have right now works (Below), but now I need to format my data.

```
<ListBox Name="lbVideos" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource listOfVideos}}"/>
```

For that i'm using a DataTemplate but the problem is that the type is Google.YouTube.Video.

```
<Application x:Class="YouTube_Notifier.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Startup="AppStartup"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:YouTube_Notifier" 
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Application.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type src:Google:YouTube:Video}">
        </DataTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The code above results in me getting the error "Type 'src:Google.YouTube.Video' was not found."

What I am asking is how do I use namespaces in a DataTemplate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The namespace containing your type needs to already be mapped in your `xmlns` attribute, i.e.

```
xmlns:src="clr-namespace:YouTube_Notifier.Google.YouTube"
```

```
{x:Type src:Video}
```

See also the [namespace mapping reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747086.aspx) and the [reference for `x:Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322.aspx)...

Comment: Well that was easier than I thought. Thank you! :-)